# How to check if stopCluster (R) worked

Tags: r, parallel-processing

When I try to remove a cluster from my workspace with stopCluster, it does not seem to work.  Below is the code I am using.

```
> cl <- makeCluster(3)
> cl
socket cluster with 3 nodes on host ‘localhost’
> stopCluster(cl)
> cl
socket cluster with 3 nodes on host ‘localhost’
```

Note that the command `cl` still is called a socket cluster with 3 nodes after I have supposedly removed it. Shouldn't I get an error that `object cl is not found`?  How do I know that my cluster has actually been removed?  A related question: if I close R, is the cluster terminated and my computer returned to its normal state of being able to use all of its cores?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't get an error that `cl` is not found, until you run `rm(cl)`. Stopping a cluster doesn't remove the object from your environment.

Use `showConnections` to see that no connections are active:

```
> require(parallel)
Loading required package: parallel
> cl <- makeCluster(3)
> cl
socket cluster with 3 nodes on host ‘localhost’
> showConnections()
  description         class      mode  text     isopen   can read can write
3 "<-localhost:11129" "sockconn" "a+b" "binary" "opened" "yes"    "yes"    
4 "<-localhost:11129" "sockconn" "a+b" "binary" "opened" "yes"    "yes"    
5 "<-localhost:11129" "sockconn" "a+b" "binary" "opened" "yes"    "yes"    
> stopCluster(cl)
> showConnections()
     description class mode text isopen can read can write
>
```

Whether or not your computer is "returned to its normal state" depends on the type of cluster you create. If it's just a simple socket or fork cluster, then gracefully stopping the parent process should cause all the child processes to terminate. If it's a more complicated cluster, it's possible terminating R will not stop all the jobs it started on the nodes.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for.  I can see the difference when I stop the cluster.  What I notice, though, is that I have two more of those connections than I thought.  Making and stopping the cluster respectively adds and subtracts three connections, but there are two left (with option all = FALSE).  That's two more than you have.  How do I know if that's another cluster I should stop or if it's something else?

Comment: @BioBroo: it's probably something specific to your setup. If you're running R from a GUI or IDE, it's possible they create connections. Or it could be something in your `.Rprofile`, the `.Rprofile.site`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `print.SOCKcluster` method doesn't tell you if the cluster object is usable. However, you can find out if it's usable by printing the elements of the cluster object, thus using the `print.SOCKnode` method. For example:

```
> library(parallel)
> cl <- makeCluster(3)
> for (node in cl) try(print(node))
node of a socket cluster on host ‘localhost’ with pid 29607
node of a socket cluster on host ‘localhost’ with pid 29615
node of a socket cluster on host ‘localhost’ with pid 29623
> stopCluster(cl)
> for (node in cl) try(print(node))
Error in summary.connection(connection) : invalid connection
Error in summary.connection(connection) : invalid connection
Error in summary.connection(connection) : invalid connection
```

Note that `print.SOCKnode` actually sends a message via the socket connection in order to get the process ID of the corresponding worker, as seen in the source code:

```
> parallel:::print.SOCKnode
function (x, ...) 
{
    sendCall(x, eval, list(quote(Sys.getpid())))
    pid <- recvResult(x)
    msg <- gettextf("node of a socket cluster on host %s with pid %d", 
        sQuote(x[["host"]]), pid)
    cat(msg, "\n", sep = "")
    invisible(x)
}
<bytecode: 0x2f0efc8>
<environment: namespace:parallel>
```

Thus, if you've called `stopCluster` on the cluster object, you'll get errors trying to use the socket connections.